# Determining cell format in excel

Tags: excel

This seems to be so simple of a request, but I was not able to find an answer. I have a numeric cell and it seems to round numbers. Can I ask excel to tell me formatting settings of a particular cell. For example if the number formatting is fraction up to one digit I would like to know that. It would also be nice to know what the other attributes are; like width, centering, and so on.

Comment: You can get some information using the `cell` function, but it's not as useful as one hopes... You need to use VBA for more details

Comment: @Amit Thanks, that was helpful. It is limited but better than nothing.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then...

Answer (score 1):

You can get some information using the `cell` function ([doc](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/CELL-function-b98b713d-d3de-4148-829f-80c886af6410?ui=en-US)), but it's not as useful as one hopes...

You need to use VBA for more details.